# Sufficient conditions for the existence of a joint distribution given any marginal probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request

We are given a set $S$ with $|S|=n$, a non-negative integer $m\le n$, and a distribution over the elements of $S$ to select a subset $S'\subseteq S$ with cardinality $|S'|=m$. Let $\mathbf{p}\in [0,1]^n$ be the vector of the marginal probabilities of including each element of $S$ into $S'$.

---

**Question:** How can we prove that, for all $m\in\{0, 1, \ldots n\}$ and *for all* $\mathbf{p} \in[0,1]^n$ such that $~\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=m$, there exists a joint distribution to select subsets $S'\subseteq S$ with cardinality $|S'|=m$?

Comment: Wait, must the joint distribution always select a subset $S' \subset S$ such that $|S'| = m$, or is the statement we want to show $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \geq m$ is a sufficient condition for the existence of a joint distribution to pick $S' \subset S$ such that there is a nonzero probability $|S'| = m$?

Comment: Thank you @1mdlrjcmed . I rephrased the problem text and the question to clarify the problem. Given an non-negative integer $m\le n$, the joint distribution always selects a subset $S'\subseteq S$ with cardinality $S'=m.$

Comment: If you're proving the sufficient case, all you need to do is come up with one joint distribution satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = m$ that fits these assumptions: you are trying to make an example, not prove a general thing. Try and think of a silly example that always produces an $m$ element subset.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed but the joint distribution must exist *for all* $\mathbf{p}\in [0,1]^n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=m$. That is, if I give you *any* $\mathbf{p}\in [0,1]^n$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=m$, you must always be able to generate a joint distribution with such marginal probabilities to select $m$-subsets of $S$.

Comment: Have you tried test cases, say for $n = 3, m = 1 ,2$ for $p_i = m/3$? Making your probability space $[0,1]$, and making columns for each element $1,2,3$ for the marginal distributions might help.

Comment: Why the tag [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory)?

Comment: I removed the theory related tags @md2perpe

Answer (score 1):

The following probability distribution over all subsets $S'$ of $S:=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ with $|S'|=m$, is directly defined in terms of the marginal probabilities $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$ of including each element $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ in $S'$ respectively:
$$\Pr\left(S'=\{x_{i_1},x_{i_2},\ldots,x_{i_m}\}\right)=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^m p_{i_j}}{m\cdot{n-1\choose m-1}}\,.$$

It is easy to verify that, for all $\mathbf{p} \in[0,1]^n$ such that $~\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=m$, the sum of these probabilities values over all subsets $S'$ of $S$ with $|S'|=m$ is equal to $1$. For all $i\in [n]$, the number of subsets $S'$ containing $x_i$ is ${n-1\choose m-1}$. Hence, if we sum the probabilities values defined above over all subsets $S'$ of $S$ with $|S'|=m$, the coefficient multiplying $p_i$ is $\frac{1}{m}$. Finally, since $~\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=m$, the sum of these probabilities values is always $1$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: I think the idea is good, but are your normalization constants right? If $n = 3, m = 2, p_1=p_2=p_3 = 2/3,$ then the probability of a given subset being sampled is $\frac{2*2/3}{2*\binom{3}{2-1}}=\frac{4/3}{2*3}=\frac{2}{9}.$ Since there are only 3 subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ of size 2, the answer should be $1/3$.

Comment: Thank you @1mdlrjcmed for your comment! Clearly once you fix any $x_i$ there are ${n-1\choose m-1}$ ways to choose the other $m-1$ elements, but I previously wrote ${n\choose m-1}$. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better visual explanation for this, but here is a written one. Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ be our probability space, $\mathbb{P}$ the lebesgue measure. This is roughly equivalent to $[0,1]$, except we will be using this quotienting to make our notation slightly easier.

Let $1,2,...,n$ be our element labels. Define the probability density of element $1$ of being in our set $S'$ to be $$f_1(\omega)= 1_{[0,p_1)}(\omega)$$ where $\omega \in \Omega \sim [0,1]$ and $1_{[0,p_1)}(\omega)$ is 1 if $\omega \in [0,p_1)$ and 0 otherwise.

Define the probability density of element $i$ being in our set $S'$ to be
$$f_i(\omega) = 1_{[p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_{i-1}, p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_i)}(\omega)$$
where we are using the quotienting to have this make sense, i.e.,
$$f_i(\omega) = 1 \iff \exists x \in [p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_{i-1}, p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_i), m \in \mathbb{Z} \; \text{ such that } \omega - x = m.$$

It is clear that we have the desired marginal distribution. It now remains to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(\omega) = m$ everywhere, as this determines our joint distribution. This is intuitively clear (I hope) but I will try to make it clear.

Imagine the function over $[0,m]$ given by $$g(x) = 1_{[0,p_1)}(x) + 1_{[p_1,p_1+ p_2)}(x) + ... + 1_{[m - p_n, m]}(x).$$
I claim that for $\omega \in [0,1]$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(\omega) = \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} g(\omega + j)$$ which is $m$ because the lengths of the intervals in $g(x)$ are all less than 1, and our intervals cover $[0,m]$.

Please let me know if the justification is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I provided a constructive proof in another answer here, which in my opinion is much simpler. What do you think about it? Do you think that the distribution answering this question is unique?